# python prints weird lines while using scapy

Tags: python, console, scapy

When I run my python code, the console prints the line

```
<UNIVERSAL> <class 'scapy3k.asn1.asn1.ASN1_Class_metaclass'>
```

How can I hide these lines?

Comment: You'll need to show us your code if you'd like help with this. It could be something you are calling that is printing to the console

Comment: @TylerMarques I know I should but it's a really really long code.. I didn't write "print (something)"

Comment: If you didn't explicitly call it, it's being called within the scapy package. You can't really silence that, other that to direct only the print statements you want to see to a different output, other than `STDOUT`

Comment: @TylerMarques oh.. okay thanks for helping!

Comment: No problem, best of luck! Just so you know, it looks like this a print statement called on a class of some kind, as that is the format generally used for a class's `__repl__` or `__str__` method.

Comment: @TylerMarques I will check that.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been fixed.

You should upgrade to the latest version (Scapy 2.4.0, via [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/scapy/) for example) or get the current development code from the [repository](https://github.com/secdev/scapy).